# How to find array in array

Tags: javascript

I need to find the elements in a first array that match with elements in a second array. For example:

```
this.languages = [
      {id: 'es', name: 'Español'},
      {id: 'fr', name: 'Frances'},
      {id: 'en', name: 'Ingles'},
      {id: 'pt', name: 'Portugues'}
];
```

Must return the languages that match win the next array:

```
this.languagesSelected = [
      'es', 'fr'
];
```

The result will be:

```
this.languages = [
      {id: 'es', name: 'Español'},
      {id: 'fr', name: 'Frances'}
];
```

Tryng from :

```
questions.filter(x => x.id === id);
questions.find(x => x.id === id);
```

I cant compare the second array.

Thanks mates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a good start using `filter()` method, but your condition is not good. You need to check if any of the languages in  `selectedLanguages` array exists in `languages` list. So here **`some()`** method will help.

*The some() method tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test*

```js
let languages = [
      {id: 'es', name: 'Español'},
      {id: 'fr', name: 'Frances'},
      {id: 'en', name: 'Ingles'},
      {id: 'pt', name: 'Portugues'}
];

let languagesSelected = [
      'es', 'fr'
];

let result = languages.filter(e => languagesSelected.some(element => e.id == element));

console.log(result);
```

Another method you can use is **`includes()`**

*The includes() method determines whether an array includes a certain value among its entries, returning true or false as appropriate.*

```js
let languages = [
      {id: 'es', name: 'Español'},
      {id: 'fr', name: 'Frances'},
      {id: 'en', name: 'Ingles'},
      {id: 'pt', name: 'Portugues'}
];

let languagesSelected = [
      'es', 'fr'
];

let result = languages.filter(e => languagesSelected.includes(e.id));;

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done efficiently by creating a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) of `id: object` pairs from your `languages` array, which you can use while you [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over your `languagesSelected` array:

```js
const languages = [ {id: 'es', name: 'Español'}, {id: 'fr', name: 'Frances'}, {id: 'en', name: 'Ingles'}, {id: 'pt', name: 'Portugues'} ];
const languagesSelected = ['es', 'fr'];

const lut = new Map(languages.map((o) => [o.id, o]));
const res = languagesSelected.map(k => lut.get(k));
console.log(res);
```

This will be `O(N + K)` vs the `O(NK)` you would get with a filter/includes/indexOf/some methods

Answer (score 1):

```
languages.filter(l=>this.languagesSelected.indexOf(l.id)>-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
const result = this.languages.filter(lang => this.languagesSelected.includes(lang.id));
```