# Check if array items are found as certain property value within array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays and I want to find matching elements of these arrays

```
const array1 = [{"id": 0, "value": 1}, {"id": 1, "value": 2}, {"id": 2, "value": 3}, {"id": 3, "value": 4}, {"id": 4, "value": 5}, {"id": 5, "value": 6}, {"id": 6, "value": 7}, {"id": 7, "value": 8}, {"id": 8, "value": 9}, {"id": 9, "value": 10}]
```

```
const array2 = [0, 1, 11, 12]
```

how can I find matching elements of `array1` and `array2`?

my expected output is

```
const array3 = [0, 1]
```

Comment: There will be no matching elements since array1 contains objects, and array2 contains strings.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if an array contains any element of another array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16312528/check-if-an-array-contains-any-element-of-another-array-in-javascript)

Comment: The principle should still apply to your case. You'll obviously need to tweak the code.

Comment: Also, your tags should be changed. This is unrelated to either `reactjs` or `react-native`.

Comment: From what we can see, you want to know how to match elements between two arrays. Isn't that what you're looking for?

Comment: Your code shows only very basic Javascript. The tags should reflect that.

Comment: @Shivam In the future, when asking a question, you should provide your inputs (which you have), your expected output (missing), and most importantly, the code you have tried so far to accomplish your goal + links to other posts that didn't work for you (also missing). If you edit your question to include these, some of the dvs might get removed

Comment: @NickParsons I will follow that.

Comment: I'm fairly your question is a dupe of this though: [How to find array in array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65717198)

Comment: @Shivam your desired output is unclear since you haven't explained the question clearly enough (see all the answers that misunderstood your question) or provided your expected output in the question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make use of [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) together with [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```js
const array1 = [{"id": 0, "value": 1}, {"id": 1, "value": 2}, {"id": 2, "value": 3}, {"id": 3, "value": 4}, {"id": 4, "value": 5}, {"id": 5, "value": 6}, {"id": 6, "value": 7}, {"id": 7, "value": 8}, {"id": 8, "value": 9}, {"id": 9, "value": 10}],
      array2 = [0, 1],
      
      
      result = array2.filter(_id => array1.some(({id}) => id === _id))
      
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

By mapping you can find your array like this

```
let array2 = ['0', '1']
let found = false;  
array1.map(ele =>{
   let found = (ele.id.toString() === array2[0].toString() && 
                ele.value.toString() === array2[1].toString())? true : false;
})
console.log(found)
```

Answer (score 2):

if i understood corretly here is how you can filter your `array1` if you want to filter on `value` use `value.toString()`

```js
function myFn() {
  let array1 = [{"id": 0, "value": 1}, {"id": 1, "value": 2}, {"id": 2, "value": 3}, {"id": 3, "value": 4}, {"id": 4, "value": 5}, {"id": 5, "value": 6}, {"id": 6, "value": 7}, {"id": 7, "value": 8}, {"id": 8, "value": 9}, {"id": 9, "value": 10}]
  let array2 = ['0', '1','11','12']

  let idArray = array1.map(a => (a.id));
  let filteredArray=idArray.filter(value=>array2.includes(value.toString()));
  console.log(filteredArray);
  
}

myFn();
```

Comment: I am expecting my result array as [0,1].

Comment: `array2` is already `[0, 1]` then what would be the relation with `array1`

Comment: if my array2 is `[0, 1, 11, 12]` then?

Comment: @Shivam see the edited answer